# Setup Codeformatter for Sublime Text 3 - Allman bracket style

Tags: php, sublimetext3, curly-brackets

I have installed Codeformatter for Sublime Text 3, because I want the Allman style for curly brackets when I hit tab. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to "activate" this feature, so it auto formats with the allman style (mainly in PHP). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Let's hope I get this right. I'm assuming you're using [sublimetext-codeformatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter). In the language specific options for PHP, add `AllmanStyleBraces` to the `passes` array:

```
"codeformatter_php_options":
{
    "syntaxes": "php",
    "passes": ["AllmanStyleBraces"]
}
```

Checkout the [WIKI](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter#php) for an example options list, and [this page](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter/blob/master/PHP-Transformations.md) for a list of PHP Transformations.

Comment: I'm using that one, yes. Now I have tried to make the change to the document, but it does not seem to have any effect. I still get the normal formatting if I type in if and then hit tab for instance.

Comment: Hmmm, could you post your formatter options file on pastebin (or wherever), the one where you placed the above code?